VSCodium Fails to Detect Virtual Environment Interpreter
I activated the virtual environment of my project via the terminal and then opened the project path in VSCodium. However, VSCodium fails to find the interpreter of the virtual environment when I try to choose a kernel. It looks like the directory in the output is somehow wrong.
Error output:
[warning] Failed to check if /home/user/code_projects/gps_data_2107/venv is an executable [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/home/ben/code_projects/gps_data_2107/venv'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'lstat',
  path: '/home/user/code_projects/gps_data_2107/venv'
}

[warning] Identifier for virt-virtualenv failed to identify /home/ben/code_projects/gps_data_2107/venv [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/home/user/code_projects/gps_data_2107'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: '/home/user/code_projects/gps_data_2107'
}

Additional Information:

VSCodium Version: 1.91.1 (release: 24193)
Python Version: 3.12.3
Operating System: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS

Error screenshot
